# Laravel 5.1 wrong data being send to view

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am displaying all projects on my homepage and wanna show how amny likes each project has. The likes are stored in the Likes table with a unique id and the project id

So in my ProjectsController I write a count query to find how many likes each project has when I echo the output in my controller everything works but in my view I always get 0 as result

My controller function

```
public function home_projects()
{
    $projects = Project::all();

    foreach ($projects as $project){
        $likes = Like::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->count();
        echo $likes;
    }

    //return $projects;
    return view('welcome', ['projects' => $projects, 'likes' => $likes]);
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
            <div class="col-md-4 grid_item">


                <a class="grid_link" href="projects/{{ $project->id }}">
                    <img class="imagebox" src="uploads/projects/{{ $project->file_name }}">
                </a>


                <div class="image_actions">
                    <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline">
                        <button type="submit" class="like_button">Like</button>
                        <label for="">{{ $likes }}</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="comment_button">Comment</button>
                        <label for="">3</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="favourite_button">Favourite</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to set model relationship. (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many)
In your model Project:

```
public function likes() {
  return $this->hasMany('Like', 'project_id');
}
```

And now your controller will be:

```
$projects = Project::all();
return view('welcome', ['projects' => $projects]);
```

View in place when you need likes:

```
{{ $project->likes()->count() }}
```

**UPD:** I fixed return value. So now in the controller to return view:

```
return view('welcome', ['projects' => $projects]);
```

Comment: I get an error on the return line in my controller Undefined variable: likes

Comment: I get this error now FatalErrorException in Model.php line 906:
Class 'Like' not found

Comment: @MoussaChaabar Did you create the Like model? Please read this reference http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many. I can not see your full project structure. And I can not say step by step what you should do. However if you create the model User and insert the proper namespace of it in `return $this->hasMany('{model namespace}', 'project_id');` everything should work.

Comment: I have fixed it by changing it to App\Like in the function likes() It works now much cleaner code thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must stock your `$likes`in an array.

Because with your actual code, the var `$likes`is always (re)set cause `foreach(){}`

Ex :

```
$likesArray = array();
foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $likesArray[] = Like::where('project_id', '=', $project->id)->count();
}
```

**UPDATE**

And to display it

```
<?php $key = 0; ?>
@foreach ($projects as $project)
            <div class="col-md-4 grid_item">


                <a class="grid_link" href="projects/{{ $project->id }}">
                    <img class="imagebox" src="uploads/projects/{{ $project->file_name }}">
                </a>


                <div class="image_actions">
                    <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline">
                        <button type="submit" class="like_button">Like</button>
                        <label for="">{{ $likesArray[$key] }}</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="comment_button">Comment</button>
                        <label for="">3</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="favourite_button">Favourite</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            // increment your key var
            <?php $key++; ?>
            @endforeach
```

By the way, **this is not a good practice**, but the fix should work

Comment: how do I exactly do this in Laravel? I am kinda new to the framework

Comment: Okay I see, so I send the array to my view like this: return view('welcome', ['projects' => $projects, 'likesArray' => $likesArray]); and then in my view I loop over the array again with a foreach?

Comment: This doesnt seem to work I get an Array to string conversion Error

Comment: Do I have to pass the entire array to the view and loop out the correct answer in my view?

Comment: Look at my update ( i'm not sure about the syntax  to declare variable in Blade )

Comment: the keys {{$key = 0}} and {{$key+1}} are being shown in the frontend

Comment: ok so replace `{{ $ i =0 }}`  by  `{{""; $i = 0 }}` AND `{{$i++}}` by `{{""; $i++}}`

Comment: it shows the results of the '0' value of the array so if value 0 is 5 it shows 5 everywhere so the incrementing of the key isn't happening

Comment: Look at my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95591/discussion-between-moussa-chaabar-and-wilson).